# Save custom Object to Application Settings does not work

Tags: c#, .net, application-settings

I have a object in an application that saves settings for this application. The instance of this object is saved in the settings of the application.

```
[global::System.Configuration.ApplicationScopedSetting()]
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
public ReportingConfiguration ReportingConfiguration
{
    get { return ((ReportingConfiguration)(this["ReportingConfiguration"])); }
    set { this["ReportingConfiguration"] = value; }
}
```

At application start up the object is read out and if its null new instantiated. After that immediately saved.

```
// Get existing ReportingConfiguration or create new if null
var reportingConfiguration = Properties.Settings.Default.ReportingConfiguration;
if (reportingConfiguration == null)
{
    reportingConfiguration = new ReportingConfiguration();
    Properties.Settings.Default.ReportingConfiguration = reportingConfiguration;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

When the settings are modified from the settings dialog and should be saved, the object is saved to the settings.

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ReportingConfiguration = _reportingConfiguration;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

However, when I restart the application, the read out object is null again. This happens at debugging and also when I try it to start without debugging.

What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible to save a custom object to settings?

Comment: When you call `Save()` you modify the *user's* settings. Your object is marked `ApplicationScopedSetting` though. Have you tried to use [UserScopedSettingAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.userscopedsettingattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) ? This won't work with ASP.NET applications as these don't have user configuration settings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes, using `UseScopedSettingAttribute` it works. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to serialize your settings based on objects. I would recommend using [Newtonsoft Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).

[Serialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) your object into a JSON string when ever you want to save it to your settings. [Deserialize](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm) the setting string to the actual object when reading out your setting.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. The *content* of the setting doesn't matter. .NET has no problem using complex settings objects